# Why is a quaternion a + bi + cj + dk not equal to a + (b+c+d)i

Tags: quaternions

i² = -1

j² = -1

k² = -1

But

a + bi + cj + dk is not equal to a + (b+c+d)i

why not ?

Comment: You left out $ijk=-1$, which is what shows you they can't be equal

Comment: This is because taking square destroy information. eg. $1^2 = 1 = (-1)^2$ doesn't imply $1 = -1$.

Comment: What is $i$, $j$ or $k$? Are they the unit vectors  used to represent the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: You probably have not studied some higher vector notes. They are assumed to be $i=(1,0,0)$, $j=(0,1,0)$ and $k=(0,0,1)$ in $R^3$.

Comment: @mrs https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Dear friend I know that. I want to be sure of it. Thanks.

Comment: Based on your record, I assumed you did, but to a casual observer your second post would seem more confusing than clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Because $i, j, k$ aren't equal. In the quaternions, $-1$ has even more square roots than it does in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d' \in \Bbb R: a + bi +cj +dk = a'+ b'i+c'j+d'k \iff a=a', b=b', c=c', d=d'$$ just as if we'd have written a $4$-tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ for the quaternion. The coefficients uniquely determine the number.

In particular $i = 0+1i + 0j + 0k \neq j = 0 + 0i + 1j + 0k$ etc. The roots of $-1$ are $i,-i,j,-j,k,-k$ already showing the quaternions are not a field (already obvious from non-commutativity: $ij=k, ji=-k$ etc.) as in a field a quadratic like $x^2+1$ can have at most $2$ roots, not $6$.